# Unable to boot Ubuntu 10.04 LTS after hibernation

Tags: boot, keyboard, hibernate

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on a desktop.

I hibernated the desktop and since then I have not been able to boot Ubuntu.

The (USB) keyboard seems deactivated and doesn't show any lights when I turn on the desktop.

I set a BIOS password but can't get beyond the prompt for password because I can't input the password with the keyboard (so booting won't occur).

Unfortunately, I can't boot from a USB to reinstall Ubuntu.

Is there a solution that is beginner-friendly because I am not very familiar with using command terminal/lines.

Answer (score 1):

If the keyboard isn't working in the BIOS stage then it's unlikely that the issue is being caused by the operating system.

Here are some things you might try: unplugging the computer/plugging it back in, different USB port, different keyboard.  If all else fails you can pull your CMOS battery to reset your BIOS settings (hence disabling the BIOS password).